# Flume: kafka channel and hdfs sink get unable to deliver event error

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, apache-kafka, flume, flume-ng

I want to try this new Flafka flow: only use kafka channel transfer data to hdfs sink. I tried it from kafka channel and logger sink which is easier to monitor. My configuration file is:

```
# Name the components on this agent
a1.sinks = sink1
a1.channels = channel1

a1.channels.channel1.type = org.apache.flume.channel.kafka.KafkaChannel
a1.channels.channel1.brokerList = localhost:9093,localhost:9094
a1.channels.channel1.topic = par4
a1.channels.channel1.zookeeperConnect = localhost:2181
a1.channels.channel1.parseAsFlumeEvent = false
a1.channels.cnannel1.kafka.consumer.timeout.ms = 1000000
a1.sinks.sink1.channel = channel1
a1.sinks.sink1.type = logger
```

I set up zookeeper and two brokers locally using above port number, and I have a producer client keep push messages to kafka.
I got following messages:

```
    2015-07-02 20:22:37,619 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.start(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:61)] Configuration provider starting
2015-07-02 20:22:37,623 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider$FileWatcherRunnable.run(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:133)] Reloading configuration file:conf/example.conf
2015-07-02 20:22:37,629 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1017)] Processing:sink1
2015-07-02 20:22:37,629 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:1017)] Processing:sink1
2015-07-02 20:22:37,629 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.addProperty(FlumeConfiguration.java:931)] Added sinks: sink1 Agent: a1
2015-07-02 20:22:37,633 (conf-file-poller-0) [WARN - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration$AgentConfiguration.validateSources(FlumeConfiguration.java:508)] Agent configuration for 'a1' has no sources.
2015-07-02 20:22:37,635 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.conf.FlumeConfiguration.validateConfiguration(FlumeConfiguration.java:141)] Post-validation flume configuration contains configuration for agents: [a1]
2015-07-02 20:22:37,635 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadChannels(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:145)] Creating channels
2015-07-02 20:22:37,639 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.channel.DefaultChannelFactory.create(DefaultChannelFactory.java:42)] Creating instance of channel channel1 type org.apache.flume.channel.kafka.KafkaChannel
2015-07-02 20:22:37,650 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.channel.kafka.KafkaChannel.configure(KafkaChannel.java:168)] Group ID was not specified. Using flume as the group id.
2015-07-02 20:22:37,658 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.channel.kafka.KafkaChannel.configure(KafkaChannel.java:188)] {metadata.broker.list=localhost:9093,localhost:9094, request.required.acks=-1, group.id=flume, zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181, consumer.timeout.ms=100, auto.commit.enable=false}
2015-07-02 20:22:37,665 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.loadChannels(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:200)] Created channel channel1
2015-07-02 20:22:37,666 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkFactory.create(DefaultSinkFactory.java:42)] Creating instance of sink: sink1, type: logger
2015-07-02 20:22:37,669 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.AbstractConfigurationProvider.getConfiguration(AbstractConfigurationProvider.java:114)] Channel channel1 connected to [sink1]
2015-07-02 20:22:37,674 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents(Application.java:138)] Starting new configuration:{ sourceRunners:{} sinkRunners:{sink1=SinkRunner: { policy:org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor@3362ba9e counterGroup:{ name:null counters:{} } }} channels:{channel1=org.apache.flume.channel.kafka.KafkaChannel{name: channel1}} }
2015-07-02 20:22:37,675 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents(Application.java:145)] Starting Channel channel1
2015-07-02 20:22:37,677 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.channel.kafka.KafkaChannel.start(KafkaChannel.java:96)] Starting Kafka Channel: channel1
2015-07-02 20:22:37,885 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [INFO - kafka.utils.Logging$class.info(Logging.scala:68)] Verifying properties
2015-07-02 20:22:37,903 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [WARN - kafka.utils.Logging$class.warn(Logging.scala:83)] Property auto.commit.enable is not valid
2015-07-02 20:22:37,903 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [WARN - kafka.utils.Logging$class.warn(Logging.scala:83)] Property consumer.timeout.ms is not valid
2015-07-02 20:22:37,903 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [WARN - kafka.utils.Logging$class.warn(Logging.scala:83)] Property group.id is not valid
2015-07-02 20:22:37,904 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [INFO - kafka.utils.Logging$class.info(Logging.scala:68)] Property metadata.broker.list is overridden to localhost:9093,localhost:9094
2015-07-02 20:22:37,904 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [INFO - kafka.utils.Logging$class.info(Logging.scala:68)] Property request.required.acks is overridden to -1
2015-07-02 20:22:37,904 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [WARN - kafka.utils.Logging$class.warn(Logging.scala:83)] Property zookeeper.connect is not valid
2015-07-02 20:22:37,929 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.channel.kafka.KafkaChannel.start(KafkaChannel.java:99)] Topic = par4
2015-07-02 20:22:37,929 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.register(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:120)] Monitored counter group for type: CHANNEL, name: channel1: Successfully registered new MBean.
2015-07-02 20:22:37,930 (lifecycleSupervisor-1-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.start(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:96)] Component type: CHANNEL, name: channel1 started
2015-07-02 20:22:37,930 (conf-file-poller-0) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.Application.startAllComponents(Application.java:173)] Starting Sink sink1
2015-07-02 20:22:37,939 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [INFO - kafka.utils.Logging$class.info(Logging.scala:68)] Verifying properties
2015-07-02 20:22:37,939 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [INFO - kafka.utils.Logging$class.info(Logging.scala:68)] Property auto.commit.enable is overridden to false
2015-07-02 20:22:37,939 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [INFO - kafka.utils.Logging$class.info(Logging.scala:68)] Property consumer.timeout.ms is overridden to 100
2015-07-02 20:22:37,939 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [INFO - kafka.utils.Logging$class.info(Logging.scala:68)] Property group.id is overridden to flume
2015-07-02 20:22:37,939 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [WARN - kafka.utils.Logging$class.warn(Logging.scala:83)] Property metadata.broker.list is not valid
2015-07-02 20:22:37,940 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [WARN - kafka.utils.Logging$class.warn(Logging.scala:83)] Property request.required.acks is not valid
2015-07-02 20:22:37,942 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [INFO - kafka.utils.Logging$class.info(Logging.scala:68)] Property zookeeper.connect is overridden to localhost:2181
2015-07-02 20:22:37,951 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [INFO - kafka.utils.Logging$class.info(Logging.scala:68)] [flume_MACC02PHH5LG3QC-1435893757951-c4c69fb7], Connecting to zookeeper instance at localhost:2181
2015-07-02 20:22:37,952 (SinkRunner-PollingRunner-DefaultSinkProcessor) [ERROR - org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:160)] Unable to deliver event. Exception follows.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: close() called when transaction is OPEN - you must either commit or rollback first
    at com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkState(Preconditions.java:172)
    at org.apache.flume.channel.BasicTransactionSemantics.close(BasicTransactionSemantics.java:179)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.LoggerSink.process(LoggerSink.java:105)
    at org.apache.flume.sink.DefaultSinkProcessor.process(DefaultSinkProcessor.java:68)
    at org.apache.flume.SinkRunner$PollingRunner.run(SinkRunner.java:147)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
^C2015-07-02 20:22:39,497 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.flume.lifecycle.LifecycleSupervisor.stop(LifecycleSupervisor.java:79)] Stopping lifecycle supervisor 12
2015-07-02 20:22:39,499 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - kafka.utils.Logging$class.info(Logging.scala:68)] Shutting down producer
2015-07-02 20:22:39,499 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - kafka.utils.Logging$class.info(Logging.scala:68)] Closing all sync producers
2015-07-02 20:22:39,501 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:150)] Component type: CHANNEL, name: channel1 stopped
2015-07-02 20:22:39,501 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:156)] Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: channel1. channel.start.time == 1435893757930
2015-07-02 20:22:39,501 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:162)] Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: channel1. channel.stop.time == 1435893759501
2015-07-02 20:22:39,501 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:178)] Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: channel1. channel.capacity == 0
2015-07-02 20:22:39,502 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:178)] Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: channel1. channel.current.size == 0
2015-07-02 20:22:39,502 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:178)] Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: channel1. channel.event.put.attempt == 0
2015-07-02 20:22:39,504 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:178)] Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: channel1. channel.event.put.success == 0
2015-07-02 20:22:39,504 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:178)] Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: channel1. channel.event.take.attempt == 0
2015-07-02 20:22:39,504 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:178)] Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: channel1. channel.event.take.success == 0
2015-07-02 20:22:39,504 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:178)] Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: channel1. channel.kafka.commit.time == 0
2015-07-02 20:22:39,504 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:178)] Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: channel1. channel.kafka.event.get.time == 0
2015-07-02 20:22:39,504 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:178)] Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: channel1. channel.kafka.event.send.time == 0
2015-07-02 20:22:39,504 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.flume.instrumentation.MonitoredCounterGroup.stop(MonitoredCounterGroup.java:178)] Shutdown Metric for type: CHANNEL, name: channel1. channel.rollback.count == 0
2015-07-02 20:22:39,505 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.flume.channel.kafka.KafkaChannel.stop(KafkaChannel.java:123)] Kafka channel channel1 stopped. Metrics: CHANNEL:channel1{channel.event.put.attempt=0, channel.event.put.success=0, channel.kafka.event.get.time=0, channel.current.size=0, channel.event.take.attempt=0, channel.event.take.success=0, channel.kafka.event.send.time=0, channel.capacity=0, channel.kafka.commit.time=0, channel.rollback.count=0}
2015-07-02 20:22:39,505 (agent-shutdown-hook) [INFO - org.apache.flume.node.PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.stop(PollingPropertiesFileConfigurationProvider.java:83)] Configuration provider stopping
```

I don't understand why I have this unable to deliver event error. (I also tried to set up HDFS sink which gives me the same error.)
I also don't understand why I didn't successfully set consumer.timeout.ms

Looking for help, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer from the community, this question can be solved by following two JIRA topic.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLUME-2734
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLUME-2735